# Why I am getting an unexpected bottom space of an image

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am beginner and I am learning HTML and CSS. I am trying to make a webpage but I am getting a problem. The problem is I am getting an extra space in the bottom of an image.

*The red mark in the image is indicating the space*

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS codes:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.food-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
      -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
          flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.food-menu .item-image {
  width: 50%;
}

.food-menu .item-image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.food-menu .item-info {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #F1F8F6;
  padding: 0 7rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.food-menu .item-info .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
}

.food-menu .item-info .sub-title {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  margin: 2.4rem 0;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33.25px;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #1E3932;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button:hover {
  background-color: #DBE5E2;
}

.order {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
}

.order .food-menu {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
}

.order .food-menu .item-image, .order .food-menu .item-info {
  width: 100%;
}

.order .food-menu .item-info{
  background-color: #D4E9E2;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="order">
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-four">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-70203.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Order and pick up. Easy as that.</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Just open the app, order your favorites, and enjoy contactless pay. From there, choose whichever pickup method is best for you.</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">See pickup options</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-five">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-72045.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Floating into summer like…</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Keep the laid-back vibes going. Order Starbucks drinks on Uber Eats.**</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">Order now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting extra space in id item-five at HTML line 27.

`#item-five > .item-image`.

Why I am getting this space?

How can I remove the space and the heights of the two divs class `item-info` must be equal.

Comment: This is happening because of text inside your second item-info just add <br> tag before your text and you are good to go

Comment: @Paulie_D While the title is the same, the actual problem here doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. Perhaps I am missing something but it looks more like a problem with grid/flexbox alignment.

Comment: @DBS the white space is the so called `inline decender space`. Images by default are inline level elements and palced on the base-line. However, there also is a decenetr space for letters like: y, j, g, p. As such you should use `img { display: block; }` to solve the issue. Thats also the solution for the linked question.

Comment: @tacoshy I understand the duplicate, however this seems like a different problem. If you take a look at the asker's example you can see they are already using `display: block` on the image.

Comment: @DBS you are right, it's due to the default align-content which is stretch by default and it need to be set as start in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align-content:start` to your grid container, you are facing the default stretch alignment

```
.order .food-menu {
  display: grid;
  align-content:start
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.food-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
          flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.food-menu .item-image {
  width: 50%;
}

.food-menu .item-image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.food-menu .item-info {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #F1F8F6;
  padding: 0 7rem;
  display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.food-menu .item-info .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
}

.food-menu .item-info .sub-title {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  margin: 2.4rem 0;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33.25px;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #1E3932;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button:hover {
  background-color: #DBE5E2;
}

.order {
  display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
}

.order .food-menu {
  display: grid;
  align-content:start
}

.order .food-menu .item-image, .order .food-menu .item-info {
  width: 100%;
}

.order .food-menu .item-info{
  background-color: #D4E9E2;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="order">
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-four">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-70203.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Order and pick up. Easy as that.</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Just open the app, order your favorites, and enjoy contactless pay. From there, choose whichever pickup method is best for you.</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">See pickup options</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-five">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-72045.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Floating into summer like…</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Keep the laid-back vibes going. Order Starbucks drinks on Uber Eats.**</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">Order now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to keep the overal height the same define a template row:

```
.order .food-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.food-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
          flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.food-menu .item-image {
  width: 50%;
}

.food-menu .item-image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.food-menu .item-info {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #F1F8F6;
  padding: 0 7rem;
  display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.food-menu .item-info .title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
}

.food-menu .item-info .sub-title {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.16px;
  margin: 2.4rem 0;
  color: #1E3932;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33.25px;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button {
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #1E3932;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.food-menu .item-info .button:hover {
  background-color: #DBE5E2;
}

.order {
  display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
}

.order .food-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
}

.order .food-menu .item-image, .order .food-menu .item-info {
  width: 100%;
}

.order .food-menu .item-info{
  background-color: #D4E9E2;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/starbucks-favicon.png">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Starbucks Coffee Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="order">
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-four">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-70203.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Order and pick up. Easy as that.</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Just open the app, order your favorites, and enjoy contactless pay. From there, choose whichever pickup method is best for you.</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">See pickup options</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="food-menu" id="item-five">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="https://content-prod-live.cert.starbucks.com/binary/v2/asset/137-72045.jpg" alt="starbucks-free-coffee">
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <p class="title">Floating into summer like…</p>
                <p class="sub-title">Keep the laid-back vibes going. Order Starbucks drinks on Uber Eats.**</p>
                <a class="button" href="#">Order now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```